# Python: turning variable's value into function's name?

Tags: python, global

Could someone, please, explain in plain English what exactly and why is going on in this little snippet:

```
def foo():
    print "You are calling a function via a variable"

var='foo'
fun_var = globals()[var]

print fun_var # it says `<function list>`
print type(fun_var) # it says `<type 'function'>`

fun_var() # it actually prints out "You are calling a function via a variable"
```

I understand that via some magic `globals()` takes the value of `var` and creates a function with the same name as the value. I also do understand that this may be quite a nice workaround if we don't know the value of `var` (e.g., it may be set by a user) and we have some functions, one of which we'd like to call depending on that value (e.g. according to the user's preferences).

However, the whole process still looks to me a bit like miracle :). What exactly globals() does here? Where do these powers are coming from? :)

Thank you.

Comment: The documentation about the [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#globals) function may be useful to you.

Comment: It's not a miracle, nor is it a good idea. I'd forget you ever learned about `globals()`, lest you decide to use it for something in the future.

Comment: @Kevin, I've actually see that one skinny line :). Still don't get the mechanism.

Comment: @Wooble, Then, again, why?

Comment: For one, because its use can make code very hard to read and debug.

Comment: Thanks to all, now, indeed, I see some light :).

Answer (score 4):

Actually...

Here you make a function called 'foo' which prints a string

```
def foo():
    print "You are calling a function via a variable"
```

Here you assign the string 'foo' to a variable 'var'

```
var='foo'
```

The globals() return a dict of global definitions which you can access trough a key, in this case 'foo' returning to fun_var the address of the foo function

```
fun_var = globals()[var]
```

Then you can see foo function attributes

```
print fun_var # it says `<function list>`
print type(fun_var) # it says `<type 'function'>`
```

Then you call foo function putting ()

```
fun_var() # it actually prints out "You are calling a function via a variable"
```

This is the same as:

```
def foo():
   print('Hello')

fun_var = foo
fun_var()  # Prints 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really that magical. `globals()` is a dictionary containing all global variable and function declarations, in the style of `{ key: value }`, where the name of the function or variable is the `key`, and the actual function or variable value is the `value`. Whenever you have a dictionary, you can ask for the value of a key with `dict["key"]`. So when you ask for the value of the thing that has key (read: name) `foo`, you get back the function named `foo`, as that's what the name is bound to in `globals()`.

That said, only mess with `globals()` if you absolutely have to. Messing with Python builtins is a dangerous game.

Answer (score 1):

globals() returns a dictionary of all the objects in your global namespace.

`globals()['key']` gives you the object mapped to the key in the dictionary.

You are passing in the key for function `foo` and the dictionary gives you back a reference to the function, which you are then binding to a variable.

No magic involved.

Answer (score 0):

globals() is a dictionary of all the globally accessible objects. You're accessing your function by passing its name as the key to that dictionary.